# Sending JWT Token in URL in wordpress

Tags: wordpress, jwt, single-sign-on

Suppose this is situation:
the Login Url you have entered in SSO setup is **https://mywordpressite.com/login**. We would hit this Url with the returnurl parameter in the following way: **https://mywordpresssite.com/login&returnurl=https://nonwordpresssite.com/mycourses**. After successful login on your wordpress, you should redirect to the following url: **https://nonwordpresssite.com/mycourses?ssoToken=.**

Basically I want wordpress to send JWT Token after login to my another platform for SSO.